How to upload multiple images and text to MySQL with PHP?
I am trying to make a multiple choice website. But for some of my questions I need to do the following:
TEXT
IMAGE
TEXT
IMAGE
etc....
All I have now is one field for text and one upload image. But that defeats the whole question that have many photos and text.
How can I do this with PHP and MySQL???
I have tried duplicating the text and upload image code. But some Questions have 4 photos and other questions have 12 photos. So duplicating the code won't work that well.
Kind off need a field where I can add text and drag and drop or copy and paste a photo.

The question is very vague as is. It sounds like you should have a question table, an image table, and a table that relates questions with images.

Multiple Choice that comes with multiple choices. Very interesting question.
As you already have found out, using the computer to solve this question already works pretty well. First results are achieved and experiments with duplication works amazingly well, already learning about its limits and when it gets stuck.
+-----------------+
| MULTIPLE CHOICE |
+-----------------+

multiple choices...

TEXT IMAGE TEXT IMAGE etc....

As far as you've learned it, you can clearly say you want to do this with PHP and MySQL. But it appears somewhat limited as you got stuck.
This is normally the time where I suggest to switch back to pen and paper. The pen draws the program (PHP) and the paper is/can also be divided, like a database. As this is much faster than using the computer and also it is much easier to start from scratch (e.g. take another sheet of paper), it's the ideal tool when you got stuck in duplicating code (which on the other hand is very fast on a computer).
Another technique is to reduce the requirements. While it is not enough to have an image only for one TEXT+IMAGE, the image is perhaps more important. Especially as the text case is already handled for the multiple choice question title. So both single cases are already technically covered and turning TEXT: IMAGE IMAGE IMAGE ... into TEXT: TEXT+IMAGE TEXT+IMAGE TEXT+IMAGE ... is certainly then much more easy to achieve.
Also while you build TEXT: IMAGE IMAGE IMAGE ... you already learn how to handle the repetition. That is, similar as with your current version, you can throw it away and build it up again with the knowledge already gained. This already helps you to think about release management: When is a software actually ready to use? How do I decide if it is ready or not?
And last but not least: With what you've learned so far, perhaps there is an existing software available written in PHP and using MySQL which perhaps does even what you're looking for? Then give it a try and see if it does, then look how others did it. This can often be very insightful.
